# How is the formula $H_{2n+1}(x)=(-1)^n\sum_{s=0}^{n}(-1)^s(2x)^{2s+1}\cfrac{(2n+1)!}{(2s+1)!(n-s)!}$ derived?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hermite-polynomials

How the relationship $H_{2n+1}(x)=(-1)^n\sum_{s=0}^{n}(-1)^s(2x)^{2s+1}\cfrac{(2n+1)!}{(2s+1)!(n-s)!}$ is deduced ,working with Hermite polynomials ?

There is a problem so I don't know how to deduce the formula and it is that when I substitute $ 2n + 1 $ in the following relation:

\begin{align}
H_n(x)&=\sum_{s=0}^{n/2}(-1)^s\cfrac{n!}{(n-2s)!s!}(2x)^{n-2s}\\
H_{2n+1}(x)&=\sum_{s=0}^{(2n+1)/2}(-1)^s\cfrac{(2n+1)!}{(2n+1-2s)!s!}(2x)^{2n+1-2s}\\
\end{align}

I get a sum whose upper limit is not a whole number.

Comment: (As usual with orthogonal polynomials) it is immediate from the generating function

Comment: The sum is from $0$ to $\lfloor (2n+1)/2 \rfloor$, which is $n$. Then, rewrite the index to do the sum from $n$ to $0$.

Comment: How can I do that chance in the index?

Comment: I'm afraid that can't be done without grabbing paper and pencil (heresy at MSE).